# Stanford CoreNLP tokenize.whitespace property not working on Chinese

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP for pos-tagging and NER on a pre-tokenized Chinese text, I read the official doc https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html, saying that the tokenize.whitespace option 'If set to true, separates words only when whitespace is encountered'. That's exactly what I want.

But I'm using python, pycorenlp to interact with CoreNLP Server and know nothing about java. Then I read the anwser [How to NER and POS tag a pre-tokenized text with Stanford CoreNLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807175/how-to-ner-and-pos-tag-a-pre-tokenized-text-with-stanford-corenlp/29807502) and thought maybe the only thing to do is to add 'tokenize.whitespace' = 'true' and another property in my post-request properties dictionary, but it simply doesn't work. I ran my server like this:

```
java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -port 9000 -timeout 150000
```

and in my jupyter notebook:

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

output = nlp.annotate('公司 作为 物联网 行业', properties={
    'annotators': 'pos,ner',
    'tokenize.whitespace': 'true', # first property
    'ssplit.eolonly': 'true', # second property
    'outputFormat': 'json'
})

for sentence in output['sentences']:
    print(' '.join([token['word'] for token in sentence['tokens']]))
```

which gives:

```
公司 作为 物 联网 行业
```

The CoreNLP is still tokenizing the token '物联网', just like if I don't add the two properties. Then I tried creating a .properties file and using it on command line instead of StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties, but it doen't work either. In my test.properties:

```
tokenize.whitespace=true
ssplit.eolonly=true
```

Then I ran the server like this:

```
  java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties 'test.properties' -port 9000 -timeout 150000
```

Still it behaved as if I had changed nothing. Does anybody know what I am missing? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved my own problem.

It's tricky to use tokenize.whitespace=true for Chinese text, seems that it never works; instead, add

```
'tokenize.language': 'Whitespace'
```

to your properties dictionary or equivalently, add

```
tokenize.language: Whitespace
```

to your .properties file to get things right done.

This property is written on the same page https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#options, which I didn't notice before. It's a little bit confusing why it exists two properties for a same purpose.